# MVC Date Formats in IEnumerable Recordset

Tags: asp.net, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

Are there issues using @item.Date.ToString with an IEnumerable recordset? The reason I ask is if I just use @item.Date, the page renders correctly but if I try to format the Date to say MonthName, for example @item.Date.ToString("MMMM") the IEnumerable recordset returns a Null value.

I actually need the Date value date breaking down to Date MonthName Year

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Oops, a bit of more reading wouldn't have gone a miss here. The correct syntax should include Value, for example:

```
@item.Date.Value.ToString("dd") @item.Date.Value.ToString("MMMM") @item.Date.Value.ToString("yyyy")
```

I hope this helps someone :-)